# Apache Superset on ECS with Athena dataset run queries async

Tags: amazon-ecs, apache-superset

I'm experimenting with Apache Superset for visualizing data from Athena. I deployed the template they provide [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/solutions/implementations/apache-superset/). Everything was fine until I've added multiple widgets on a dashboard, utilizing the same dataset but with different filters (12 to be precise, 1 for each month). The problem is that they are obviously loading one after another, which takes more time and sometimes causing issue 1000 and 1001. Here is Athena history which shows this, 1-3 second lag between requests, more than 20 seconds between first and last, although each query execution takes about 2 seconds:

[image: Athena history]

So my question is if there is a way to make dataset run queries asynchronously utilizing architecture they provide in template?